# Angular Material - move md-secondary to the left

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

How do you move a `md-secondary` button to the left side instead of the default right side? Normally

```
<md-list-item ng-click="foo()">
    <span>Stuff</span>
    <md-icon class="md-secondary" ng-click="bar()">icon</md-icon>
</md-icon-item>
```

this creates a nice list item, but I want the icon to be on the left. I tried reordering the elements

```
<md-list-item ng-click="foo()">
    <md-icon class="md-secondary" ng-click="bar()">icon</md-icon>
    <span>Stuff</span>
</md-icon-item>
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the class from `md-secondary` to `md-primary`.

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item ng-click="itemClick()">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="btnClick()">
      <md-icon class="md-primary" md-font-icon="mdi-web"></md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <span>Stuff</span>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/trevorhreed/pen/jqYwNY) for a more detailed example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however when I tried it if I click on the icon it thinks I clicked on the item itself. Any idea why?

Comment: Take a look at the codepen I referenced. It's working as expected (clicking the item and clicking the icon have different results).

Comment: Well I did (and I made sure that I have the exact same thing as yours) but it doesn't seem to do it

Comment: The codepen does work, but it doesn't work on my code :(

Comment: Perhaps if you could create a codepen that reproduces the issue you're having I could better identify the problem.

Comment: In your example, your angular material css was `v1.1.0-rc2` but your angular material javascript was `v1.0.4`. Updating your javascript reference resolves the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/44jfjdkk/1/

Comment: I updated the library to 1.0.7 (latest stable) and it is still not working like in 1.1.0 rc2. Is there any way to make it work in 1.0.7 or I will have to go for rc2?

Comment: Nevermind, I updated to 1.1.0 (while hoping it doesn't break anything) and it worked well. Thanks.